# Unable to save the String text and attach it to the mail in android

Tags: android

I'm having some trouble with attaching the txt file to the gmail.
I called the saveItToText() method that creates a txt file from a string value, and called sendEmail() to attach the generated txt file to the gmail, however, when I open the gmail app it says that "Cannot attach empty file". I may have some mistakes in the logic in the following code below. All I want to do is to attach a file that contains a string to the email. I searched around the web but cannot find a good solution. I would love to hear from you !

```
 public void saveItToText(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    , mFileName);
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
            android.util.Log.d("Test","gpx "+root.toString());
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(root);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendEmail(String email) {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                , mFileName);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        android.util.Log.d("Test", "path: "+path.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        //intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        String to[] = { email };
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mUrl);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."),
                1222);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1222) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    , mFileName);
            file.delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well before you send a file to an email app you could check if the file exists. And check its length. Did you?

Comment: The weird part is that it does exist. I checked it with the logcat.

Comment: ???? One cannot check if a file exist with a logcat. How would you? Use the File class in your app to do that.

Comment: `void saveItToText()`. A void function? Dont you want to know if the text really got saved? Make it return a boolean. And check return value.

Comment: Thank you , I will check it out.

Comment: `root.mkdirs();`. Check the return value! `if(!root.mkdirs()) return false;`.

Comment: mFileName for a directory? And sFileName? Pretty confusing.

Comment: `file.delete();`. You really try to delete a directory there? Confused with sFileName? And not checking the return value?

Comment: `addFlags()` does not make sense for such a file uri.

Comment: if(!root.mkdirs()) doesn't return false.  Sorry, The code I posted wasn't meant to be shown since it's a total chaos.